# Delete multiple columns in a column space in cassandra by its value

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am having a cassandra column family to keep a value with the time-stamp as follows

```
KEY   | 0001 | 0002 | 0003 | 0005 | 0008 | 0011 | ...
Value | t_1  | t_2  | t_1  | t_3  | t_1  | t_2  | ...
```

I want to write a cql query to delete all the column records in the column family.

Example: Query to delete all the columns where value equal to t_2. It should delete 0002 and 0011 columns.